# Django trying to use wrong Database User

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

SOLVED: I was using USERNAME, not USER from previously attempting Postgres driver.

I'm trying to connect my django project to an RDS MySQL database. I can connect fine using my credentials in MySQL Workbench and mysql command line.

I've set the AWS Security Group and VPC Security Group with 
 All traffic | All | All | 0.0.0.0/0

Let's say my credentials are 
User: abc
Password: password

When I run `python manage.py migrate` it is attempting to login with Mike, not abc for some unknown reason (Mike is the Windows User). How do I prevent this? Attached is my settings.py:

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'playercomp',
        'USERNAME': 'abc',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'xxx.xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
try:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except ImportError:
    print "Failed to import pymysql" 
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "playercomp.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Error Trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 27, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 342, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 61, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 263, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\pymysql\__init__.py", line 90, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 688, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 906, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1114, in _request_authentication
    auth_packet = self._read_packet()
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 981, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 393, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Envs\playercomp\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, u"Access denied for user 'Mike'@'host-yy-yy.zzz.zz.com' (using password: YES)")
```

Comment: to avoid confusions, you should copy paste your exact settings.py file. There is many a slip between cup and lip. If you are worried that we will login to your mysql server don't leave it open to the whole world. RDS security groups should only allow traffic from the same VPC

Comment: Show us the part of `manage.py` that sets the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable.

Comment: Edited with full files

Comment: Is the posted settings file `playercomp/settings.py`, or is it some other settings.py file?

Comment: Yes, it's `playercomp/settings.py`. Directory Structure:
    playercomp/ 
      manage.py  
      playercomp/  
      settings.py

Comment: Hmm.  Try running `python manage.py shell` and then print the database settings directly (`from django.conf import settings; print settings.DATABASES`) Also `print settings.__file__` to make _sure_ it's using the right file.

Comment: {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'USERNAME': 'abc', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'NAME': 'playercomp', 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'HOST': 'xxx.xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com', 'USER': '', 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'TEST': {'COLLATION': None, 'CHARSET': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}, 'PASSWORD': 'password', 'PORT': '3306'}}

Comment: Thanks for all the help @JohnGordon

Answer (score 1):

I added a field 'USER': 'abc' to the DATABASES default, and that worked.

Comment: `USER` does seem to be the correct field name.  Any idea how yours got changed to `USERNAME`?

Comment: I would prefer another explanation, but quite frankly it was probably a user error.